# measurability of integrated functions

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, measure-theory, pr.probability, integration

Hello everybody,

**DISCLAIMER**: I'm not a mathematician, but a computer scientist, so I hope the question is not trivial (or perhaps I hope so, in order to get a definitive answer). Anyway it's not a homework, as actually I'm working on some problem where the question arises.

Let $X$ be a $0$-dimensional Polish space (which in particular means we have a countable basis $\mathcal{C}$ of basic clopen sets).

Let $\mathcal{M}(X)$ be the set of *probability* measures over $X$. These are uniquely determined by assigning compatible values in $X$ to the basic clopen sets, i.e.  there is a bijection between $\mathcal{M}(X)$ and a subset of the space $\mathcal{C}\rightarrow [0,1]$.

Let $(X,\Sigma^{B})$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.

Let $(X, \Sigma^{\mu})$ be the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ of all $\mu$-measurable sets.

Let $(X, \Sigma)$ be the $\sigma$-algebra, where $\Sigma=\bigcap_{\mu\in \mathcal{M}(X)} \Sigma^{\mu}$. This is indeed a $\sigma$-algebra.

**QUESTION 1**
Is it actually possible that $\Sigma \not = \Sigma^{B}$? I think they should not be necessarily the same, but that's just an intuition. Obviously $\Sigma^{B}\subseteq \Sigma$, since $\forall \mu. \Sigma^{B}\subseteq \Sigma^{\mu}$.

**QUESTION 2**

Let $\phi: X \rightarrow [0,1]$ be a $\Sigma^{B}$-measurable function (i.e. inverse images of basic open sets are Borel).

Let $\mathcal{M}(X)$ be endowed with a topology. You can assume that this is also a $0$-dimensional polish space.

Let us define the function $g:\mathcal{M}(X)\rightarrow [0,1]$ as follows:

$g(\mu) = \displaystyle\int_{X} \phi \ d \ \mu$

is $g$ (Borel)-measurable?

**QUESTION 3**
Same as question $2$, but taking $g$ just $\Sigma$-measurable  (i.e. inverse images of basic open sets are in $\Sigma$). This is of course an interesting question only depending on the "outcome" of Question 1.

I kind of strongly suspect that the answer to Question 1 is YES. After all I'm plugging Borel measurable functions with integral operations, and that should be safe. 
But i'm less sure about Question 2, in particular perhaps $g$ is not Borel measurable in general, but (something-else)-measurable. I'm not sure.

Thank you in advance for any answer!

bye

matteo

**PS**: Perhaps I should add some detail about the topology I have in mind for $\mathcal{M}(X)$. This basically is defined taking as basic open sets, the sets $S_{C,\lambda}$ of probability measures $\mu$, such that $\mu(C)>\lambda$, for $C\in\mathcal{C}$ and $\lambda$ rational in $[0,1]$, or something like that. I haven't worked out the details so far, but that would be my guess.

Comment: All uncountable Polish spaces are Borel isomorphic. So the answer to your first question is yes, for any uncountable Polish space. $\Sigma$ is the universal sigma algebra, but this is quite standard.

Comment: See

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_measurable_set

for the basics about universally measurable sets.

Comment: Hi George and Bil! thanks a lot for the answers!

@George: just to be sure (since you also gave an answer below), $\Sigma$ - the universal $\sigma$-algebra$ - on an uncountable Polish space does **not** coincide with $\Sigma^{B}$, right?
Just wanted to be sure about the meaning "YES".

Anyway I borrowed Kechris "Classical Descriptive Set Theory", so tomorrow i'll search for it.



















Comment: @Matteo: I didn't give an answer below, but yes, $\Sigma$ does not coincide with $\Sigma^B$. Here's an example of an element of $\Sigma\setminus\Sigma^B$ for the real numbers; http://planetmath.org/?op=getobj&from=objects&id=11351 (or, if you prefer, in the irrational real numbers, which is zero dimensional).

Comment: @George: Uh, embarrassing!! I miss-read Gerald below with George and just assumed it was the same entity :) I must be a bit tired.
Thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Question 1.
Your $\Sigma$ is known as the $\sigma$-algebra of *universally measurable sets*.  And, yes, there are universally measurable sets that are not Borel sets.

Question 2.
You say "a topology" ... there is a commonly-used one, the *narrow* topology, obtained by declaring that $\mu \mapsto \int \phi\,d\mu$ is continuous for any continuous $\phi$.  (I believe this coincides with the one in your PS, since you are taking only this zero-dimensional case.)  With that topology, your answer is "yes".

Comment: Hi gain Gerald :)

Beside point $1$, which you answered already, could you please expand a little bit on points 2-3?
Unlike for "universal $\sigma$-algebra", wikipedia does not seem to cover "narrow topology". 

Could expand and/or you give me some reference on this? (I already have Kechris' "Classical Descriptive Set Theory") just from the post I'm not sure I understood what the opens are in the narrow topology.

And, if you have time, could you expand a little bit on your intuition that "my topology" coincides with the narrow one for $0$-dimensional POlish spaces?

thanks in adanve.

Comment: Yes, "narrow" is also called "weak" or "weak*", which can be confusing.  If $\phi \colon X \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function and $U$ is an open set in $\mathbb R$, then $\{\mu \colon \int \phi\, d\mu \in U\}$ is a basic open set for this topology.


Comment: Once you have $\mu \mapsto \int \phi\,d\mu$ continuous for every bounded continuous $\phi$, you easily get $\mu \mapsto \int \phi\,d\mu$ Borel for every bounded Borel $\phi$.  This is because the class of bounded Borel functions is the smallest class containing the bounded continuous functions and closed under limits of pointwise-convergent sequences.


Comment: Note that this topology does make $\mathcal{M}(X)$ a polish space, but not a $0$-dimensional one. Indeed, if $x\neq y\in X$ you can produce continuous curves $t\mapsto t \delta_x +(1-t)\delta_y$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac mass.

Answer (score 1):

I know in computable analysis, which is closely related to the descriptive set theoretic questions you are asking, that the [Lévy–Prokhorov metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%25C3%25A9vy%25E2%2580%2593Prokhorov_metric) on the weak topology is useful.  (I think the narrow topology mentioned by Gerald Edgar is the same.  Also it is called the weak* topology in functional analysis. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures.)

If your space $X$ is a separable metric space, then $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is also a separable metric space under the Lévy–Prokhorov metric.  Further if $X$ is a computable metric space, then $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is a computable metric space under the Lévy–Prokhorov metric.  (I'm not sure if such computable concerns matter to you, but a proof that it is computable can be found in this paper: [Computability of probability measures and Martin-Löf randomness over metric spaces](http://www.loria.fr/~hoyrup/random_metric.pdf), along with other useful facts.)

Update: Also I should mention that there are (at least) two definitions of a computable measure $\mu$ on $X$.  One is that you can, given a finite union $U$ of open basis sets $B_1,\ldots B_k$, compute all rationals $\lambda$ such that $\mu(U)>\lambda$.  The other is that it is a computable point in the Lévy–Prokhorov metric on $\mathcal{M}(X)$.  The first definition seems similar to what you are looking for, but without the computability concerns.  Again, the paper I mentioned above shows the equivalence of these two definitions.  (But then again, there may be more standard references that don't dive into the computable stuff.)